# SQL Server Account Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am currently using SQL Server 2005 and I try to restore a database from couple of months ago but when I restore it when I try to create a account it tells me that the account already exists but you cannot see it under security. I tried dropping that account but it tells me that the account does not exist to drop...But when I try to create it, it tells me that it exists... It is driving me insane. I completely removed that account from the server and all the linked servers and all the databases and I tried to re-create it again it works on all database except one that it keeps on saying it already exists. Any ideas what it could be or what else I should be checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a DBA, I get this problem all the time.  And the GUI is not much of a help.  Your SQL server has the accounts you want, the db has the accounts you want, but they don't auto-connect on restore.

The REAL way to fix this is to STOP-USING-INDIVIDUAL-ACCOUNTS.  Only provide access to DBs on the basis of being a member of an active directory group.  Then you can give access issues to the AD-group.  BTW:  While individual accounts don't auto-reconnect on a restore, group-access does.

Here is some code I use to address the same issue.

```
create procedure [dbo].[proc_FarSyncLogins] @TargetDB nvarchar(128)= '' as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    declare @cmd varchar(1000)

    begin try
        drop table master.dbo.NeededUsers
    end try
    begin catch
        print 'could not: drop table master.dbo.NeededUsers'
    end catch

    set @cmd='select name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS as name,is_disabled 
                into master.dbo.NeededUsers
                from ['+@TargetDB+'].sys.sql_logins'

    --print @cmd
    exec(@cmd)

    print 'logins that need to be enabled'
    select * from master.dbo.NeededUsers

    declare @UserName nvarchar(128)
    declare SyncUsers1 cursor fast_forward for SELECT Name FROM master.dbo.NeededUsers

    OPEN SyncUsers1
    FETCH NEXT FROM SyncUsers1 INTO @UserName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            set @cmd = ''
            if @TargetDB <> '' 
            begin
                set @cmd=@cmd+'Use ['+@TargetDB+']; '+char(10)
            end
            begin try
                SET @cmd = @cmd+'ALTER LOGIN ['+@UserName+'] ENABLE; '+char(10)
                SET @cmd = @cmd+'exec sp_change_users_login @Action=''Auto_Fix'', @UserNamePattern ='''+@UserName+'''; '+char(10)
                PRINT @cmd
                EXEC(@cmd)
            end try
            begin catch
                Print 'Failed :'+@cmd
            end catch

            FETCH NEXT FROM SyncUsers1 INTO @UserName
        END
    CLOSE SyncUsers1
    DEALLOCATE SyncUsers1
end
```

Then just

```
exec master.dbo.proc_FarSyncLogins '<yourDBName>';
```

It IS determinately HACKY, you will want to read the output carefully to verify you meant to do all those actions.  But most of the time you just want to restore everything that you had before.

Answer (score 2):

You are having orphaned user accounts in database. It is very common issue when you copy/move your database from one server to another server. You will need to remove them from database user Or more better option is to create Server Login and map that login with that orphaned database user.
While back I wrote about it in [my blog](http://gaurangpatel.net/managing-orphaned-database-users-in-sql-server) with some demo script, you may want to look at it. Or just look at [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx) for use of SP which can be used to manager orphaned users.

Answer (score 1):

The account exists in the database and at the server level.

So you need to drop the account from the database itself but not from the server as it deosn't exist there. 
have you tried...

```
use {yourdatabasename}
go
EXEC sp_dropuser '{username}'
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the quick reply. Yeah I tried that and it does not work... Still gives me an error that the user does not exist to delete.

Comment: do you see it here... select * from sys.sysusers

Comment: and you can look in master for it here... select * from sys.syslogins